# Chrome v45 and ShellinABox

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

We have a web application that runs within a VPN. It has a self signed cert on it and is accessed through the server's IP address.

Part of the functionality of this app are some legacy Java apps (that no longer run in Chrome). Our initial work around for our Chrome users was to run Shell In A Box within an iframe of the web app to run those. All was good until the latest version of Chrome, v45.

What we’re seeing is that appears to be blocking the iframed content (maybe because of the self-signed cert?). If we grab the ShellinABox URL and drop it in a new tab, it works as it used to in the iframe. If we go back to the iframe, it now works. If we close Chrome and open it back up, it still works.

I should also note that we tried the canary builds as well. It's up to v47.x and we still see the same behavior there. We were reading through some of the Chrome group/bug lists and saw some reports that were similar but the "fixes" supposedly going through canary still didn't resolve it.

So, it appears that an exception is being logged somewhere. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior and is there a way to set this exception without jumping through those hoops?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was due to a permissions issue with ShellInABox that didn't reveal itself until v45 of Chrome, for some odd reason.